# Docker can not find the file generated by the build process in webpack project

Tags: docker, webpack

I have a webpack project and I want to run an azure pipeline on it. I build the project using `npm run build`. This returns me with a server/sever.js file in the root. Then, I create a `data` folder in the root. Then,  I run the command `node server/server.js generate` which generates the sitemap.

My webpack.config.js:

```
//webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  target: "node",
  entry: {
    main: "./src/index.ts",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './server'),
    filename: "server.js" // <--- Will be compiled to this single file
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /^pg-native$/ })
  ]
};
```

My Dockerfile:

```
# Installs Node.js image
FROM node:14.15.5-alpine3.13

# sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, COPY command
# all files we put in the Docker container running the server will be in /usr/src/app (e.g. /usr/src/app/package.json)
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copies package.json, package-lock.json, tsconfig.json, .env to the root of WORKDIR
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "tsconfig.json", "webpack.config.js", "./"]

# Installs all packages
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN mkdir -p data

# Build the project to create server/server.js
RUN npm run build

RUN ls -al /usr/src/app/server

# Change server/server.js permissions to make it executable
RUN chmod +rx server/server.js

# Runs the npm script to start the server
CMD [ "node", "server/server.js", "generate" ]
```

My package.json script:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon",
    "prod:start": "node server/server.js generate",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "webpack",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "pre-commit": "npx lint-staged",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
...
```

My azure-pipeline.yml:

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    docker -v
    docker-compose -v
    docker-compose up --build
  displayName: 'Verify Docker and Docker Compose Installation'
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app

  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:${DB_PORT}'
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}

volumes: 
 data: {}
```

Whenever I run this using `docker compose up --build`, it returns me this error:

```
api       | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/server/server.js'
api       |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
api       |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
api       |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
api       |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
api       |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
api       |   requireStack: []
api       | }
```

One thing to note here is that the `server/server.js` and `data` directory are in the `.gitignore`. Hence they will not be pushed. The data directory is created by this command in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p data
```

The server/server.js is created when this command runs:

```
RUN npm run build
```

I tried running `docker compose up --build`. I expect the Docker to have the `server/server.js` file built and run it using `node server/server.js generate` but the `server/server.js` is not found. When I manually go inside the Docker using `docker run -it <image-name> sh` and `ls` it, it has the `server/server.js` file in it.